# android application will stop when I use navHostFragment in my activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments

I want to use navigation bottom menu with using navHostFragment in main activity. But when I run the program ,it stops on setContent in onCreat method MainActivity java code.
I try to use bindig class insted setContent directly but nothing changes.

this is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.omarket.ui.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.omarket.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   // <--- it stops here, i use debuger to understand it.
    }
}
```

this is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_bar_background"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/large_icon_size"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_host_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main_graph" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation_main_graph.xml in navigation directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.settings.SettingFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setting" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoriteFragment"
        android:name="com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.favorites.FavoriteFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_favorite"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorite" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/productsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.products.ProductsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_products" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="fragment_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

</navigation>
```

errors that I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.omarket, PID: 8090
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.omarket/com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.omarket:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.omarket:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.omarket:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.omarket:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.omarket:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:628)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1066)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:639)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:592)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:557)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:539)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.omarket.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:613)
            ... 46 more
```

Befor using navHostFragment , when i use frame layout it works.
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `HomeFragment` doesn't have no parameters constructor.
If you want to use fragment that requires constructor parameters you need to provide `FragmentFactory` to navigation component.

Add empty constructor `HomeFragment()` to HomeFragment, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked. My constructor in HomeFragment class was private because I wont to be singleton class. Thanks a lot.